# Database applies ALL previous migrations on update and NOT just the new one

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a website which, as of current, both has a production and a test database.
The production database is hosted externally while the test database is hosted locally.

Whenever I make changes to my database I apply the changes through a migration.
After having added a new migration I run the **update-database** command on both my production and test database to keep them in sync.

I applied the migration just fine to my production database, however, when I wanna apply the migration to my test database I see that it attempts to apply ALL the previous migrations (and not just the new one):

Here is the output:

> Applying explicit migrations: [201603230047093_Initial,
>   201603232305269_AddedBlobNameToImage,
>   201603242121190_RemovedSourceFromRealestateDbTable,
>   201603311617077_AddedSourceUrlId,
>   201604012033331_AddedIndexProfileAndFacebookNotifications,
>   201604012233271_RemovedTenantIndexProfile,
>   201604042359214_AddRealestateFilter]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201603230047093_Initial. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Cities' in the
>   database.

Obviously it fails since the current state of the database is at the second latest migration. However I wonder why it attempts to apply ALL the previous migrations?

Unlike the production database (which has had all the migrations applied one at a time), the test database was deleted and created at the previous migration so its migration history table only contains one row:

```
201604012239054_InitialCreate
```

(I assume InitialCreate is an auto generated name of all the previous migrations combined).

**In summary:**

*Why is the test database trying to apply ALL the previous migrations instead of just the newly added?*

EDIT:
When running COMMMAND I get the follow output script:

```
DECLARE @CurrentMigration [nvarchar](max)

IF object_id('[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @CurrentMigration =
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId]
        FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = N'Boligside.Migrations.Configuration'
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC)

IF @CurrentMigration IS NULL
    SET @CurrentMigration = '0'

IF @CurrentMigration < '201603230047093_Initial'
```

(it proceeds making if statements for each previous migration)

The current migrations table in my database looks the following (note that the first row is for a logging framework so it's not related):
[image]

Comment: Try this to debug: generate a complete script update-database -Script –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase. Now examine your Test database's __MigrationHistory table and make sure MigrationId and ContextKey match what the script is checking for each migration. I can give you a workaround if that doesn't help you.

Comment: @SteveGreene
I have generated the script and I see that the ContextKey is "N'Boligside.Migrations.Configuration'" which doesn't match the ContextKey name of the row in the database which is "RealestateSiteModel.RealestateSiteDbContext". I have also updated my question with the script output.
Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Since PROD is working, just change the context keys for the migrations that exist in TEST to match. You could also just comment out the Up() code for the migrations that already ran, but that will insert more records in __MigrationHistory if you care.

Comment: @SteveGreene
I use the same dbcontext for both testing and production and simply swap out the connection string when changing between the two.

What do you mean with "change the context keys for the migrations"?

Comment: In the database tables. EF checks __MigrationHistory to see what's been run.

Comment: Your __MigrationHistory should look the same in TEST and PROD, except for the latest PROD update row perhaps.

Comment: @SteveGreene
I have no idea why the migration table of the test database had the wrong context key, but I deleted the database, and performed a new update and now the context key is right along with all the migrations being applied nicely.
Thanks for your help. Thanks to you I, not only solved my problem, but also have a better understanding of how migrations work :)
(You can add an answer if you want so I can accept it)

Comment: @SteveGreene, I'm having the same problem, but my context keys are not different.  Any ideas?  ('ve posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38881187/403404 )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One issue that can cause migrations to rerun is if your context key changes which can happen during refactoring. There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1) Update the old records in __MigrationHistory with the new values:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
   SET [ContextKey] = ‘New_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration’
 WHERE [ContextKey] = ‘Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration’
```

2) You can hard code the old context key into the constructor of your migration Configuration class:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    this.ContextKey = “Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration”;
}
```

Here is a good article on how migrations run under the hood: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

See also http://jameschambers.com/2014/02/changing-the-namespace-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-first-databases/

Comment: Absolutely beauteous  :-)